# RSpec features database always empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I recently tried making feature specs for a project but for some reason the database seems to always be empty even though I already instantiate using factory girl. The test below always fails since it cannot seem to find any entries even though using puts on Restaurant.count and @resto.inspect yields actual values.

Here's my rails_helper:

```
    # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'
require 'support/factory_girl'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migration and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/support"
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
      if config.use_transactional_fixtures?
        raise(<<-MSG)
          Delete line `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` from rails_helper.rb
          (or set it to false) to prevent uncommitted transactions being used in
          JavaScript-dependent specs.

          During testing, the app-under-test that the browser driver connects to
          uses a different database connection to the database connection used by
          the spec. The app's database connection would not be able to access
          uncommitted transaction data setup over the spec's database connection.
        MSG
      end
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end  

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    end

    config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
      # :rack_test driver's Rack app under test shares database connection
      # with the specs, so continue to use transaction strategy for speed.
      driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs = Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test

      if !driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs
        # Driver is probably for an external browser with an app
        # under test that does *not* share a database connection with the
        # specs, so use truncation strategy.
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      end
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.append_after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

  Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
    config.integrate do |with|
      with.test_framework :rspec
      with.library :rails
    end
  end

  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
  end

end
```

Code snippet:

```
  before(:each) do
    @resto = FactoryGirl.create(:restaurant, :name => "Some Restaurant", :user_id => owner1.id, :status => 'Accepted')
  end
      context "No Rated Restaurants" do
        scenario "Display No Restaurants Available" do
          expect(page).to have_content("No Restaurants available yet")
        end
      end

      context "Rated Restaurants Available" do
     #   let!(:rating1){FactoryGirl.create(:rating, :restaurant_id => restaurant1.id, :user_id => rater1.id, :rate => 3)}
            #
        before(:each) do
          FactoryGirl.create(:rating, :restaurant_id => @resto.id, :user_id => rater1.id, :rate => 3)
        end

        scenario "Display Top Rated Restaurants" do
          within(:css, "div#restaurants") do
            puts "THIS IS THE COUNT: #{Restaurant.count} #{@resto.inspect}"
            expect(page).to have_content("#{@resto.name}")
          end
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **puts** yields the actual value like.

```
puts "THIS IS THE COUNT: #{Restaurant.count} #{@resto.inspect}"
```

if the output of this line contains Restaurant count confirms that the database is not empty and it persist the Restaurant that is created by factory girl.

But if the test is failing it is may be due to the page is not having the content @resto.name
    `expect(page).to have_content("#{@resto.name}")`

I think you are expect the page to contain resto.name without revisit the page. try to revisit the page after creating restaurant.

you can use

```
visit '/your_page_route' #this will visit the page which is having the content.
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I just checked if my addition to restaurant table exists outside my test and found out that it did not, after performing a puts in the controller method

Comment: did you try to use visit method to the page where you are expecting the contents?

Comment: yes I have it in my outermost context. I haven't really changed pages at all since this is my first few tests.

Comment: you need to revisit after creating restaurant and rating, then only your changes will appear on the page. make sense?

Comment: wow...that worked...weird I thought my before(:each) visit home_path already did that...thanks a lot power...I've been stuck on that for two days now :)